# Python sockets - connecting using the same src IP/Port doesn't work

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have the server bind to a particular port:

```
serv_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serv_sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serv_sock.bind((gethostname(), MAGIC_FLOW_PORT))
serv_sock.listen(MAX_MAGIC_FLOWS)

while True:
    (client_sock, address) = serv_sock.accept()
    print "Accepted a flow"
```

And the client does this:

```
client_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client_sock.bind((gethostname(), MAGIC_FLOW_PORT+1))
client_sock.connect((server_ip, MAGIC_FLOW_PORT))
while True:
    client_socket.send("ABCDEF") 
    time.sleep(5)
```

So the expectation is client sends a TCP/IP packet with src port MAGIC_FLOW_PORT+1 and dst port MAGIC_FLOW_PORT every 5 seconds.
I enabled tcpdump in the server and I can see the packet as expected every 5s. However, the server prints the "Accepted a flow" only once, and nothing after that.

However if I comment this line in the client socket:

```
client_sock.bind((gethostname(), MAGIC_FLOW_PORT+1))
```

client then generates a packet with a different src port every time and the server accepts that. I also tried the server with

```
serv_sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
```

I still don't the second packet picked up the server.

Can I connect with the same src IP/port multiple times to the same server?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Binding to a certain port should always work if you have the permissions to do so (<1024 you need to be root) and no other socket is inhabiting the same port on the same interface.

Except, if you use `SO_REUSEPORT`, then you can bind multiple *listening* sockets to the same port.
Just think about it, how would the server side know where to send the reply? (Assuming no anycast routing magic here.)

If you comment out that `client_sock.bind()` then the kernel picks a free port as the source of your connection, so that explains why the port is different after every `connect()`.

The counterpart of the server's `accept()` is the client's `connect()`, not `send()`. So you should get an `accept()` call to return every time some other socket connects to that listening socket. If you want to react to received messages you should use `client_sock.recv()`. ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv)).